# How to group different elements without IDs, delete duplicates and add group Id in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, duplicates, grouping

I want to regroup two elements inside a new element based on their position in a list, delete duplicates of those pairs, sort them alphabeticaly and give each group a numerical id (using XSLT 2.0 or 1.0). I'm a total newbie to XSLT and currently at a total loss of how to solve my problem.

In a flat XML list of landmarks (from a database) there is a list of names for landmarks and a list of coordinates. They need to be rearranged so that each name and coordinate are grouped together correctly inside a new landmark element. Name in position 1 needs to be paired with the first coord element and so forth.

In the last three days, I looked up the topics for regrouping, duplicate removal, muenchian grouping in stackoverflow and tried out the posted examples but I'm unable to apply it to my case.

The simplified input file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<landmarklist>
  <citylist id="1">
    <landmark type="city">
      <name>London</name>
    </landmark>
    <landmark>
      <name>Tower Bridge</name>
      <name>Big Ben</name>
      <name>St Paul's Cathedral</name>
      <name>Big Ben</name>
      <coord>51°30′20″N 0°04′31″W</coord>
      <coord>51° 30′ 3″ N, 0° 7′ 28″ W</coord>
      <coord>51° 30′ 49″ N, 0° 5′ 53″ W</coord>
      <coord>51° 30′ 3″ N, 0° 7′ 28″ W</coord>
    </landmark>
  </citylist>
  <citylist id="2">
    <landmark type="city">
      <name>Paris</name>
    </landmark>
    <landmark>
      <name>Eiffel Tower</name>
      <name>Arc de Triomphe</name>
      <name>Louvre</name>
      <coord>48° 51′ 29.6″ N, 2° 17′ 40.2″ E</coord>
      <coord>48° 52′ 25.68″ N, 2° 17′ 42″ E</coord>
      <coord>48° 51′ 40″ N, 2° 20′ 11″ E</coord>
    </landmark>
  </citylist>
  <citylist id="3">
    <landmark type="city">
      <name>Madrid</name>
    </landmark>
    <landmark>
      <name>Plaza Mayor</name>
      <name>Almudena Cathedral</name>
      <coord>40° 24′ 55.31″ N, 3° 42′ 26.63″ W</coord>
      <coord>40° 24′ 56.11″ N, 3° 42′ 52.41″ W</coord>
    </landmark>
  </citylist>
</landmarklist>
```

The resulting output file should look that this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<landmarklist>
<citylist id="1">
  <landmark type="city">
    <name>London</name>
  </landmark>
  <landmark id="1">
    <name>Big Ben</name>
    <coord>51° 30′ 3″ N, 0° 7′ 28″ W</coord>
  </landmark>
  <landmark id="2">
    <name>St Paul's Cathedral</name>
    <coord>51° 30′ 49″ N, 0° 5′ 53″ W</coord>
  </landmark>
  <landmark id="3">
    <name>Tower Bridge</name>
    <coord>51°30′20″N 0°04′31″W</coord>
  </landmark>
</citylist>
 <citylist id="2">
   <landmark type="city">
     <name>Paris</name>
   </landmark>
   <landmark>
     <name id="4">Arc de Triomphe</name>
     <coord>48° 52′ 25.68″ N, 2° 17′ 42″ E</coord>
   </landmark>
   <landmark>
     <name id="5">Eiffel Tower</name>
     <coord>48° 51′ 29.6″ N, 2° 17′ 40.2″ E</coord>
   </landmark>
   <landmark id="6">
     <name>Louvre</name>
     <coord>48° 51′ 40″ N, 2° 20′ 11″ E</coord>
   </landmark>
 </citylist>
  <citylist id="3">
    <landmark type="city">
      <name>Madrid</name>
    </landmark>
    <landmark id="7">
      <name>Plaza Mayor</name>
      <coord>40° 24′ 55.31″ N, 3° 42′ 26.63″ W</coord>     
    </landmark>
    <landmark id="8">
      <name>Almudena Cathedral</name>
      <coord>40° 24′ 56.11″ N, 3° 42′ 52.41″ W</coord>
    </landmark>
  </citylist>
</landmarklist>
```

In order to use a key to group the name and coord element I used a separate transformation to add IDs (and I temporarily renamed the city name so that it won't be counted for the IDs). Or can everything be managed in own transformation scenario?

```
  <landmark>
     <name id="1">Tower Bridge</name>
     <name id="2">Big Ben</name>
     <name id="3">St Paul's Cathedral</name>
     <name id="4">Big Ben</name>
     <coord id="1">51°30′20″N 0°04′31″W</coord>
     <coord id="2">51° 30′ 3″ N, 0° 7′ 28″ W</coord>
     <coord id="3">51° 30′ 49″ N, 0° 5′ 53″ W</coord>
     <coord id="4">51° 30′ 3″ N, 0° 7′ 28″ W</coord>
  </landmark>
```

But how can I use the id of two different elements now to regroup? The examples that I found have always used one as far as I understand? I'm so sorry for my lack of understanding of how it all works.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is it enough to check for duplicates by looking only at the name?

Comment: It seems that both name and coord are relevant for deciding if it's a duplicate. There are entries in the original file that have the same name but a slightly different coord, or identical coords with different names. I would later go through the remaining entries that are duplicates either by name or coord.

Comment: Okay. How critical is the sequential numbering of the `id` attribute? Would you settle for a unique id in another format?

Comment: Also, would you not prefer to group by name and put all the coordinates with the same name inside the same `landmark` wrapper?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a sequential numbering, another format would be just as fine. The XML schema of the output format only allows one name and one coord in the landmark element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group and sort in one pass and in the second use `xsl:number` for the `id` attributes, the following is XSLT 3 (works with Saxon 9.8 or later or Altova 2017 or later):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:mode name="group" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="first-pass">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="group"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$first-pass/node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="citylist/landmark[not(@type)]" mode="group">
      <xsl:variable name="coords" select="coord"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="name" composite="yes" group-by="., let $p := position() return $coords[$p]">
          <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()[1]"/>
          <landmark>
              <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
              <coord>{current-grouping-key()[2]}</coord>
          </landmark>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="citylist/landmark[not(@type)]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:attribute name="id">
              <xsl:number level="any" count="landmark[not(@type)]"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifp8/1

Can of course be adapted to XSLT 2 if needed:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="#all">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node()" mode="#current"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="first-pass">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="group"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$first-pass/node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="citylist/landmark[not(@type)]" mode="group">
      <xsl:variable name="coords" select="coord"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="name" group-by="concat(., '|', for $p in position() return $coords[$p])">
          <xsl:sort select="."/>
          <landmark>
              <xsl:variable name="p" select="position()"/>
              <xsl:copy-of select="., $coords[$p]"/>
          </landmark>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="citylist/landmark[not(@type)]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:attribute name="id">
              <xsl:number level="any" count="landmark[not(@type)]"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltransform.net/gVAjbSZ

Comment: Thank you very much, Martin. It works beautifully. You made my day and week. Thanks for all your time and effort on the question.